# Update an image block style programatically

Tags: images, javascript, block-editor

I am trying to update the default classname of an image block that is being added to a page. In the editor backend view, I have a select drop down using ACF plugin, which programmatically changes the default image drop down style (adds a class)

When a user updates an option in the editor view, javascript calls the following function:

```
updateDefaultImgStyle() {
this.removeDefaultStyles();
wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/image', {
  name: this.activeCategory,
  label: this.activeCategory,
  isDefault: true
});
```

}

```
removeDefaultStyles() {
wp.blocks.unregisterBlockStyle(
  'core/image',
  [ 'retailResidential', 'weddingsEvents', 'advertisingEditorial']
);
```

}

However this does not seem to be updating the default 'style' for additional image blocks. If I manually click on the style, it is added. Does the blocks object need to be refreshed? or is there a better way to be doing this?

Many thanks for reading.